# iOS CoreData and AES 256 encryption

Tags: ios, encryption

I have a CoreData with user information, as Password and other critical information. I need to encrypt this information with AES 256. Looking around I have seen that there are many information about how to do this on OSX, but not on iOS. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Use the Keychain for sensitive information.

Comment: I thought of this, but it is not only related to one records, its for all the CoreData, with a lot of user data

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 5 and later Core Data by default uses NSFileProtection to protect persisted data.

You should use `NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey` to encrypt data of your store.

```
NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey  : NSFileProtectionComplete};

if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[self storeURL] options:storeOptions error:&error]){
     [self presentError:error];
 }
```

This will automatically encrypt the data of your core data.

But if you want to encrypt selected attributes you can check this [code](https://github.com/rsravan/CoreDataEncryption).It is for iOS and uses AES algorithm for encryption.